# How do I merge two columns into one new one?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to merge the first name and surname columns of this table into a new column but I'm not getting it to work. I've tried a few variations but I get very similar errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT *,
CONCAT(full_dataset.First_name, " ", full_dataset.Surname) AS Full_name
FROM full_dataset
```

gives me

```
ERROR:  column full_dataset.first_name does not exist
LINE 2: CONCAT(full_dataset.First_name, " ", full_dataset.Surname) A...
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "full_dataset.First_name".
SQL state: 42703
Character: 18
```

whilst

```
SELECT *,
CONCAT("full_dataset.First_name", " ", "full_dataset.Surname") AS Full_name
FROM full_dataset
```

gives me

```
ERROR:  column "full_dataset.First_name" does not exist
LINE 2: CONCAT("full_dataset.First_name", " ", "full_dataset.Surname...
               ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 18
```

I've also tried ("First_name", " ", "Surname") amongst other variants

[This is a section of my table (edited to remove private info)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCbCO.jpg)

Thank you very much for any help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Strings must be enclosed in single quotes in SQL:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Answer (score 1):

Don't Use "" Double Quote inside Concat Function Used ' Single Quote
Try Following

```
SELECT *,
CONCAT(full_dataset.First_name, ' ' , full_dataset.First_name) AS Full_name
FROM full_dataset
```

Comment: I tried this code: `SELECT *,
CONCAT(full_dataset.First_name, ' ', full_dataset.Surname) AS Full_name
FROM full_dataset`

Unfortunately i get this error
`ERROR:  column full_dataset.first_name does not exist
LINE 2: CONCAT(full_dataset.First_name, ' ', full_dataset.Surname) A...
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "full_dataset.First_name".
SQL state: 42703
Character: 18`

Comment: i have try this its perfectly run can you give your create table and table data screenshot for understanding the issue